# Defining the conditional distribution of $Z$ as $E^{*}[Z| \mathcal{F}](f):=E[f(Z)| \mathcal{F}]$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

I've been reading the first section Furstenberg's [Noncommuting Random Products](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-108-03/S0002-9947-1963-0163345-0/S0002-9947-1963-0163345-0.pdf) and I am confused with how he is defining conditional distribution.

Here he is considering a group $G$ acting on a space $M$. For a $M$-valued random variable $Z$, he defies the distribution $E^{*}[Z]$ of $Z$ as the functional on $C_{b}(M)$ (bounded continuous real valued functions on $M$)

$$E^{*}[Z](f)=E[f(Z)]$$

I interpret this as integrating $f$ with respect to the distribution of $Z$.

He then considers $Z$ to be a random variable on some $\Omega$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, and defines the conditional distribution $$E^{*}[Z| \mathcal{F}](f):=E[f(Z)| \mathcal{F}]$$

and states that $E^{*}{[Z|\mathcal{F}]}$ 
is itself a random variable with values in the space of probability measures on $M$.

I'm confused because $E[f(Z)|\mathcal{F}]$ looks to be the [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Classical_definition) of $f(Z)$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ which is  itself a random variable on $\Omega$. I'm also not seeing how  $E^{*}[Z|\mathcal{F}]$ is itself a random variable.

Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Here is a sketchy answer. As you correctly guessed, $E^*[Z]$ corresponds to what one uses to call the “law”, or “distribution”, of $Z$. $E^*[Z|\mathcal{F}]$ is the *conditional law* of $Z$, which is a law-valued random variable. Morally, for a given $\omega \in \Omega$, assume that you already have all the information on $\mathcal{F}$ (at point $\omega$): then it remains some uncertainty on $\omega$, and the value of $E^*[Z|\mathcal{F}]$ at $\omega$ is the law of $Z$ when you consider that remaining uncertainty. So, $E^*[Z|\mathcal{F}]$ maps $\Omega$ to the dual space of $C_b(M)$.

Comment: PS. Your question is not research-level and hence should rather be asked on math.stackexchange. Which is why I did not write a full-detail answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal M}$
$\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal G}$
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}$
$\newcommand{\P}{\mathsf P}$
$\newcommand{\E}{\mathsf E}$
Suppose that $M$ is a Polish (i.e., complete separable metrizable) space with the Borel sigma-algebra $\M$ over it. Let $Z$ be an $M$-valued random variable (r.v.) defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\G,\P)$. Let $\F$ be a sub-sigma-algebra of $\G$. The key here is that then there exists a so-called regular conditional probability distribution [(Theorems 1.13 and 1.17, and Remark 1.7 on pp. 8--9)](http://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~becherer/outline_stoch2_ws1718.pdf) $\mu_Z\colon \Omega\times\M\to[0,1]$ such that

1. for each $\omega\in\Omega$, the map $\M\ni B\mapsto \mu_{Z;\omega}(B):=\mu_Z(\omega,B)$ is a probability measure and
2. for each $B\in\M$, $\P(Z\in B|\F)=\mu_Z(\cdot,B)$ almost surely (a.s.).

So, for each $\omega\in\Omega$ and each $f\in C_b(M)$, we can introduce $\mu_Z(f)(\omega):=\int_M f\,d\mu_{Z;\omega}$; then it is easy to see that 
$$\mu_Z(f)=\E(f(Z)|\F)=E^*[Z|\F](f). 
$$
a.s. So, we can identify $E^*[Z|\F]$ with $\mu_Z$, which can in turn be identified with the random probability measure $\Omega\ni\omega\mapsto\mu_Z(\omega,\cdot)$.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer and reference!